# cordova-plugin-facebook4 Couldn't Make The App Start (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an existing app which this plugin runs fine, but today it decides to fail on me.

I can be certain that the below will very likely to re-produce the issue, once the plugin was installed, the app resulted to a blank screen after running "cordova run android". Terminal showed "LAUNCHED SUCCESS", no errors/stack trace.

**Versions:**

- cordova-plugin-facebook4: 2.4.0
- cordova: 8.0.0
- cordova-android: 7.0.0
- Android Studio: 3.1.4 (for Mac) with Android API 28

**To reproduce this:**

1. Fresh install of Android Studio and cordova, accept all licenses from Android e.g. `sdkmanager --licenses`. Make sure that app is registered in developers.facebook.com with get a proper APP_ID.
2. Terminal: `cordova create appy222 appy222.com appy222`
3. cd into the appy222
4. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="whateverid" --variable APP_NAME="Appy222"`
5. Insert the xml fragment to cordova-plugin-facebook4's plugin.xml `<config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
       <string name="fb_app_id">$APP_ID</string>
       <string name="fb_app_name">$APP_NAME</string>
     </config-file>`
6. Change the "android-minSdkVersion" to **16**. The original was 15, it complained `Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library...` when doing `cordova run android`
7. `cordova platform add android` this will install cordova-android@7.0.0
8. Run by hooking up to the Android mobile phone with develop options enabled. Terminal: `cordova run android`

And the result was a blank screen...black. The app will run fine without cordova-plugin-facebook4.

Wonder if anybody came across this problem? Hope that someone could share some thoughts here.

Comment: cordova version? cordova-android version? 
beside that, what's the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Cordova version is stated up there (8.0.0), cordovan-android version is stated up there (7.0.0).No stack trace at all. The app deployed to the mobile with "LAUNCH SUCCESS". I wanted to inspect on the error through chrome://inspect, but it doesn't even have an entry.

Comment: weird that there isn't a single entry. have you try to add some console.log to track what is happening?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, I'd fired up adb logcat and filter the logs with the package name. It gives: "ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/appy2.com-2/lib/arm

Comment: OK, found the solution...gees, got to down scale the Facebook's Android SDK version to just 4.28.0

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. What worked for me was removing the plugin, setting the facebook android sdk version to 4.35.0:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="whateverid" --variable APP_NAME="Appy222" --variable ANDROID_SDK_VERSION="4.35.0"

Then removing and readding the android platform:

cordova platform rm android

cordova platform add android

Comment: I'm just curious as to how to obtain the right Android SDK Version number

Comment: My app started failing after updating to the latest version of the plugin 2.4.0 which uses SDK 4.36.0. App worked fine on the prior plugin version which was on SDK 4.35.0 so I reverted to that.

Comment: OK, found the solution...gees, got to down scale the Facebook's Android SDK version to just 4.28.0

Answer (score 1):

Android build.gradle couldn't found $FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION.
So I changed it in ionic-cordova-facebook4 plugin.
You can find root/plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/plugin.xml file.

Here you can find this setting

please change it to

finally 
ionic cordova platform rm android, 
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android
Now All is ok!

Comment: Where can we find that setting?

Comment: You can find that this directory.
root/plugins/codova-plugin-facebook4/plugin.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to my own question/problem. Seems that I need to down the Facebook's Android SDK version all the way to just 4.28.0 (instead of 4.36.0 which is the current at the moment of writing).

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="whateverid" --variable APP_NAME="whateverappname" --variable ANDROID_SDK_VERSION="4.28.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade Facebook Android SDK version to 4.26.0

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="app_id" --variable APP_NAME="app_name" --variable FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION="4.26.0" --variable ANDROID_SDK_VERSION="4.26.0"

Remember to set both the variables ANDROID_SDK_VERSION & FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION to avoid conflicts as some of the versions of cordova-plugin-facebook4 was referring to variable ANDROID_SDK_VERSION

Remember to remove and add android platform again.

Answer (score -1):

Me too. I got the solution.It must be same name Google Play Package Name in dev facebook app and wiget id in config.xml.

Comment: Not in my case...the app id is matching.